API to Disable Email Notifications Across All ACC Projects programmatically
Is there an APS API that allows disabling email notifications across all ACC hub projects? I couldn't find relevant information in the available documentations.
Thank you in advance :)

The feature you are requesting for is currently not available. You can however log a ticket with your business case using the form at https://aps.autodesk.com/contact-support for the team to consider the same as a wishlist item.
